# Animated icons with java and CSS

Tags: animation, javafx, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to use `FontAwesome` animated icons in my `JavaFX` application, which is written without `@FXML`.

When I'm using normal `Fontawesome` icons in my application I'm getting them as a `Text` object using `GlyphsDude.createIcon(icon)` from the [GlyphsDude](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.jensd/fontawesomefx/8.1/de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphsDude.java) library. Is it possible to keep using the same concept and incorporate animated icons in this?

I couldn't find any prior art on how use animated `FontAwesome` icons in `JavaFx` applications without using `@FXML`.

I tried adding the `fa-spin` class when loading my icons. Like this:

```
Text icon = Icons.getIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.COG);
icon.getStyleClass().add("fa-spin");
```

But that does not work. Probably because the `font-awesome.css` and `font-awesome.min.css` that contains the `fa-spin` class isn't found. So I tried including them by doing:

```
scene.getStylesheets()
        .add(getClass().getResource("xx/font-awesome.css").toExternalForm());
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("xx/font-awesome.min.css").toExternalForm());
```

But it turns out that these `CSS`-files isn't compatible with JavaFX (I think), since they give me an "CSS error parsing file" error on a number of lines when loaded.